# Upload jpg with flask and html

Tags: python, html, database, flask, upload

I'm a beginner and i'm making a blog with flask and html right now but it only can post title and content, but i want to post some picture init, so if anyone know whats the essayist way to post it (print the pic on flask app) and can storage in db file, can u please help me out? Because i'm stuck in this for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a flask form to upload a file, then `from flask_wtf.file import FileField` can be used as the form field to upload files.

```
class UploadImageForm(Form):
    file = FileField(label='File Upload')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

On the HTML side you will want:

```
<form action="{{ url_for(your.route, **kwargs) }}" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  {{ form.name_of_file_field }}
  {{ form.submit }} <!-- Or an input tag -->
</form>
```

Then your route that will be called when the form is submitted must require a POST method. In development, you can store your files locally within the static folder, but I would advise to store them in remote storage before putting the app on a server.

Once the file is stored and uploaded, then in your html you can render the image with:

`<img class="image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename=image_file_path) }}">` where image_file_path is the path to the image. This path should be stored as an environment variable. The image file name can be stored on your db within one of your models data columns as a string. I suggest creating UUID's as the image file name so you are not dependent on the user's upload (i.e. if the filename is in a different language).

Miguel Grinberg has a great tutorial on this that will cover all of this and more including working with image objects, image validation, and security: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask

Comment: should i add a route for that?

Comment: Depends if you have an existing route you want to use and the structure of your app. But yes, you will need a route for the form submission, image object validation, and storing the image and the file path to the image